# Do bots have their own Chat IDs?

Tags: telegram, pyrogram

Do bots have `chat_id` like user accounts? Where can I find it? I want to use it to send messages to my bot using `pyrogram`.

Answer (score 1):

Chat IDs are the same for everyone that accesses that chat. In private messages (1-to-1 chats), `chat_id == user_id`.

Two Examples:

- The `chat_id` of `@PyrogramChat` is `-1001387666944`, no matter who accesses or retrieves it.
- `@PyrogramBot` has the `user_id` `483849041`, to send it a message you can use that ID as the `chat_id`.

As for how to send messages, see the [Documentation](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/send_message).

Comment: I was trying to use id which I've received from `api.telegram.org/bot-token-/getMe` page, but pyrogram says that `Peer id invalid`. So I'm confused about it.

Comment: Actually, I can't even get `message.text` received from bot. It seems like pyrogram user bot can't see messages from my bot.

Comment: UPD. Any requests to bot user_id or user_ids of new bots that I've created ending with `Peer id invalid` error.

Comment: These comments are not a Forumthread. If you need further help, either create a new specific Question, or ask in the [Pyrogram Community](https://t.me/pyrogramchat)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do, bot tokens are in that format - `BOT_ID:SOME_STUFF`, in here BOT_ID is your bot's id.